# Render form after validation fails

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am using Play Framework 2 and want to minimize code duplication when work with forms and validation.

I have controller that renders form and handles form submission:

```
def create() = Action { implicit request =>
  //create form
  //DB calls to build comboboxes and tables
  Ok(views.html.create(form, ...))
}

def handleCreate() = Action { implicit request =>
  createForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      //DB calls to build comboboxes and tables
      BadRequest(views.html.create(formWithErrors, ...))
    },
    obj => {
      //other logic
  })  
}
```

The problem is in `//DB calls to build comboboxes and tables` part. I do not want to duplicate this part. Sure, I can extract it to method and then call it both in `create` and `handleCreate` methods.

Is it any more elegant way to deal with this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is two separate HTTP calls and since Playframework is stateless there is no direct way to store that data in a server side "session" bound to the same client (unless you implement something like that yourself of course).

What you could do however is use the Play Cache API around the DB calls, make sure the data is immutable and then use the cached data *if* it still is in the cache when the second call arrives and avoid the extra DB-calls that way. This way it could possibly be shared by more than one client as well, depending on how general the data you read out of the DB is.

Comment: Is it any kind of best practice for this situations? Something like DAO or so?

Comment: I would rely on common sense rather than best practice. If your app has got DAOs then that might be a good place to do caching, but it very much depends on your usecase, there might certainly be cases where you do some expensive mapping/combining/etc on the data from your DB in a controller specific way and in that case it would be better to place the cache logic in the controller. Or extract that combining logic and the caching to a separate class etc.